# Excel automation through Windows Task Scheduler throwing an error - 80080005 Server execution failed

Tags: excel-2016, windows-task-scheduler, office-automation

We have a **console application** to automate the excel data refresh everyday at a particular time of the day. It is working fine when we switch off the office updates. But when an office update happens, immediately this stops working and throwing this error:

`"exception Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE))."`

But when we try to execute the same console application through command prompt, it is working fine and when the same is scheduled through **SQL agent**, then also it is working fine. Only the task that scheduled in the Task Scheduler is not working.

Workaround tried so far:

1. Set the Microsoft Excel Component's identity to "The Interactive user". This is working fine when a user is logged on to the server. So, this cannot be a permanent solution.
2. Tried to create the following folders in the windows directory.

   "C:/Windows/System32/config/systemprofile/Desktop", "C:/Windows/SysWOW64/config/systemprofile/Desktop",

still it is not working.

I am using Microsoft Excel 2016 and the server is Windows Server 2016.

Any leads on this will be very helpful.